# change frontend language wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change my theme language in the frontend from english to german . I have changed also wp-config.php file . But it doesn't work. I am using wordpress 4.0
Can some one what should to do change language?

Comment: you want to change all the text to a different language or the dashboard?

Comment: i want change all the forntend text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Get the the language pack (e.g. `de_DE.mo`) from [wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language). If the language pack isn't available as a standalone download, you could also use the `.mo` file which is bundled in the WordPress ZIP-file for your language. Located under `wp-content/languages`.
2. Move the `.mo` file to `wp-content/languages/` of your default (english) WordPress installation.
3. Change the `WPLANG` constant in `wp-config.php` to the new locale (e.g. `de_DE`)
4. In your `functions.php` add the following filter:

**functions.php**

```
add_filter('locale', 'wpse27056_setLocale');
function wpse27056_setLocale($locale) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}
```

**Reference** - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/different-language-for-frontend-and-backend

Take a look at WordPress Codex - **[Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)**

Additionally you can use WP plugins especially for translating your WP website: 
**[Codestyling Localization](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/)** 
**[User Language Switch](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-language-switch/)**

Comment: This does work, but there are a couple of caveats with Wordpress 4 and up: **1)** If you go to `Settings->General`, the site language dropdown will say `English (United States)` despite the set language of your site, and if you change & save any General settings without changing that dropdown every time, your _whole site_ will revert back to English; **2)**  you may need exceptions for any permalink-language-dependent URLs (for example, some ajax actions or particular WooCommerce actions)

Answer (score 1):

Setup your site in the desired language in the admin settings and then download this plugin. In it you can setup the language for your admin backend side only ;)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kau-boys-backend-localization/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google translate plugin for wordpress. For more info see the plugin page.

[Google Translate WordPress » WP Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-translate/)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change the language in the front-end and keep the language in the backend the same. I tried using adding a filter to in `function.php` but that didn't work for me. What did was using a plugin - [Backend localization](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kau-boys-backend-localization/)

Answer (score 0):

**Change Language of Woocomerce through Functions Or change language of wodpress**

```
/* ==== Function Start ==== */

add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply44');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply44');

function translate_reply44($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Undo?', 'numaları sipariş silindi. Sepete geri almak istiyorsanız tıklayın? ', $translated);
return $translated; 
}

/* ==== Function END ==== */
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 4.7, you should do the following:

```
function wp_noshor_redefine_locale($locale) {
    if( is_admin() ):
        switch_to_locale('en_US');
    endif;
}
add_filter('init','wp_noshor_redefine_locale');
```

this changes the dashbaord to English while setting front-end to the language you choose from the setting option.